# switching between URL to retrieve json based on button element visibility using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to javascript and I have setup a web page to retrieve sensors that provide data from sensors, however I also push the values from sensor to mysql database. So I have made a button on the web page that displays a live button `liveBtn` and and a database button `dbBtn` based on which button is visible URL is set to either retrieve json from mysql or live from sensors. I want to know which of the below is better approach to set the URL:

by default in HTML page I have made database button `dbBtn` hidden and `liveBtn` live button visible.

**1st**

```
hostName = window.location.hostname;

function urlSwitcher(){

if ($('#dbBtn:not(:visible)'))  {
        url ="http://" + hostName + "/arduino/directEncode.php";
  } else 
  {
        url = 'http://' + hostName.replace("192.168.1.3", "192.168.1.156");  + ':8095/json';
  }
  return url;
}

 // or the 2nd one.

function urlSwitcher(){
    var liveBtn = document.getElementById("liveBtn");
    if (liveBtn.style.display !== 'none') {
      url ="http://" + hostName + "/arduino/directEncode.php";
    } else {
      url = 'http://' + hostName.replace("192.168.1.3", "192.168.1.156")  + ':8095/json';
    }
}
```

I want to know how should I put or what should I have setup that it executes correctly on the page load. So once the page is loaded URL is available for ajax call.

Comment: You need `$('#dbBtn').is(':hidden')`. `$('#dbBtn:not(:visible)')` will always return an object which is truthy and thus code in `if` will be executed.

Comment: You might also want to consider using two seperate buttons and just show one or the other based on the URL you are currently displaying?

Comment: @AlexPánek thats what I am doing. this was the first when I figured out https://jsfiddle.net/seaurchin/hum9sb1o/

Comment: Using jQuery also checks other ways in which an element can be hidden other than style.display = 'none' which may be good or bad depending on your use case. https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz Aah, my bad. Understood that differently.

Comment: @Tushar which jquery version are you referring to ? `$('#dbBtn').is(':hidden')`doesnt work